# Is there a better way to optimise this purge query?

Tags: sql, oracle, procedure

I have to create a oracle procedure to delete all the data of customers whose subscription status is cancelled and the data is older than 2 months.
There are 500 million total records and around 100 million have to be deleted.

I have to create a script so it deletes 5 million in each run as doing the entire thing together will take too long.
This is what I have created. Is there any way to further optimise it?

```
DECLARE
    rows_deleted   NUMBER := 0;
    max_rows_to_delete NUMBER := 5000000;
    retention_date DATE := trunc(sysdate) - INTERVAL '2' MONTH;
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM subs
    WHERE
        EXISTS (
            SELECT
                1
            FROM
                Sub_status ss
            WHERE
                    sub.id = ss.id
                AND ss.status= 'cancel'
        )
        AND sub.date <= retention_date
        AND ROWNUM <= max_rows_to_delete;

    rows_deleted := SQL%rowcount;

    -- Log number of rows deleted
    dbms_output.put_line('Deleted ' || rows_deleted || ' rows');

    COMMIT; -- Commit changes after successful completion
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        -- Handle exceptions or errors if necessary
        ROLLBACK; -- Rollback the transaction if an error occurs
        dbms_output.put_line('Error: ' || sqlerrm);
END;
```

Comment: Please tag your posting properly!!!  MySQL and Oracle are 2 completely different products with different syntax.  The code above can't be for both of them.  Please remove the wrong tag.

Comment: Delete for 5M rows is not what may be improved by any additional structures. Define your table as partitioned, truncate partitions and insert the data you don't want to delete. It should be much faster

Comment: @astentx table is partitioned by date but partition cannot be used for delete as entire partition is not dropped, only records which are cancelled

Comment: You can define a composite partitioning on range(date), list(status). That way you can easily drop subpartitions matching the date range and cancelled status. Just be sure to tell it to enable row movement as a change in status will literally move a row from one subpartition to another.

Comment: @PaulW i cannot change the schema. It's an enterprise database :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a function that takes an `id` and does a lookup on `sub_status` and returns the `status`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE getsubstatus(in_id integer)
  RETURN varchar2 DETERMINISTIC PARALLEL_ENABLE
AS
  PRAGMA UDF;
  var_status;
BEGIN
  SELECT status
    INTO var_status
    FROM sub_status
   WHERE id = in_id;

  RETURN var_status;
END;
```

If your table is partitioned, then get the partition names of those partitions old enough for archiving by querying `all_tab_partitions`, and for each one, move (reorg) the partition using the syntax:

`ALTER TABLE subs MOVE PARTITION p202301 INCLUDING ROWS WHERE getsubstatus(id) != 'cancel' PARALLEL(16)`.

If your table is not partitioned, then simply do:

`ALTER TABLE subs MOVE INCLUDING ROWS WHERE getsubstatus(id) != 'cancel' PARALLEL(16)`.

Oracle will internally create a new segment composed only of rows with a status other than `cancel`. Inserting survivors is *much* faster than deleting if your targeted rows to delete are a significant portion of the segment. 20% (100m out of 500m) is very significant.

Comment: Thank you but the table is unpartitioned and I will not be able to change that

Comment: @Sam, you said in an above comment to astentx, "  *table is partitioned by date but partition cannot be used for delete as entire partition is not dropped* ". Which is it? Partitioned or not?

Comment: @Sam, if it's not partitioned, simply remove the phrase `PARTITION p202301` from the  `ALTER TABLE` in my answer. The same technique applies whether it's partitioned or not. My point is that a `ALTER TABLE MOVE` can delete rows efficiently, even if you depend on another table for a lookup, which can be accomplished by way of a function. My method is a lot less resource-intensive and time-consuming than your `DELETE` is.

Comment: @Sam, edited my answer to clarify that you can do this whether your table is partitioned or not.